# Wordpress editor: "pick from existing tags" is gone?

Tags: tags, block-editor

In the olden days of Wordpress, I could compose a new post and pick from existing tags using the "Tags" section in the right sidebar. With the current editor, that "Tags" section still lets me enter new tags - but "pick from existing" is gone.

[image]

Short of opening the list of existing tags in a new window (`/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag`), how do I get this useful functionality back?

Comment: Thanks for the migration; I got the impression that this site is more for developers rather than users like myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

[image]

It's been on discussion [2 years ago](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/1341) and I think it is one of the reasons why Gutenberg is not really beloved by many people.

If you don't rely on Gutenberg and need the feature so badly, you can use a plugin that enables the Classic Editor for posts, at least.

I know that is not a perfect solution, but I'm not aware of any plugin to do what you need for Gutenberg and maybe your posts are of simpler nature, so that they won't need Gutenberg at all.

Comment: Precisely. I have chosen to install the plugin "[Disable Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/)". As per its description: *The all-in-one, COMPLETE solution for handling Gutenberg. Hide ALL traces of Gutenberg and replace with the Classic Editor. Restores the original Edit Post screen (TinyMCE, meta boxes, et al).*

Comment: In my honest opinion, this was a good choice. If you require block editing for pages later on, I would always recommend to pick one of the leading page builders over Gutenberg, there are even free options. Maybe Gutenberg will catch up in the next years.